# Value of 'this' is null in an onClick method for ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

The error happens on the `onClick` method of `<span className="nav-toggle">`. The error is: ***cannot read property setState of null***.I think it's an issue with the scoping of `this` or because `setState` is an async method. That's why I've tried using the recommended method in the docs (using setState with a function instead of passing in a new state object).

```
export default class NavigationBar extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   isMobile: this.props.isMobile
  };
 }

render() {
 console.log('Rendering component');
 return (
  <header className="nav has-shadow">
   <div className="nav-left">
    <Link className="title" to="/">Food Diary</Link>
   </div>

   <span className={ (this.state.isMobile) ? 'nav-toggle is-active' : 'nav-toggle'} onClick={this.toggleMobileNav}>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
   </span>

   <div className={ (this.state.isMobile) ? 'nav-right nav-menu is-active' : 'nav-right nav-menu'}>
    <Link className={(this.props.currentActivePage === 'Home')? "nav-item is-active" : "nav-item"} to="/">
     {(this.props.loggedIn) ? 'Home' : 'Login | Register'}
    </Link>
    <Link className={(this.props.currentActivePage === 'Dashboard')? "nav-item is-active" : "nav-item"} to="/dashboard">
     Dashboard
    </Link>
    <Link className={(this.props.currentActivePage === 'Account')? "nav-item is-active" : "nav-item"} to="/account">
     My Account
    </Link>
    <span className="nav-item">
     <a className="button is-dark" href="https://github.com/">
      <span className="icon">
       <i className="fa fa-github"></i>
      </span>
      <span>Github Repository</span>
     </a>
    </span>
   </div>
  </header>
 );
}

toggleMobileNav() {
 console.log('Got inside toggleMobileNav');
 this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  return {
   isMobile: !prevState.isMobile
  };
 });
}
};
```

Comment: Gotta bind events handlers and `this` a la `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);` which you can read up on [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it works now! I've been trying to find documents and answers on SO for this problem for hours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind `this` to handlers:

```
export default class NavigationBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
       isMobile: this.props.isMobile
      };
    this.toggleMobileNav = this.toggleMobileNav.bind(this); // BIND TO THIS
  }

  render() {
   console.log('Rendering component');
   return (
    <header className="nav has-shadow">
     <div className="nav-left">
      <Link className="title" to="/">Food Diary</Link>
     </div>

     <span className={ (this.state.isMobile) ? 'nav-toggle is-active' : 'nav-toggle'} onClick={this.toggleMobileNav}>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
     </span>

     <div className={ (this.state.isMobile) ? 'nav-right nav-menu is-active' : 'nav-right nav-menu'}>
      <Link className={(this.props.currentActivePage === 'Home')? "nav-item is-active" : "nav-item"} to="/">
       {(this.props.loggedIn) ? 'Home' : 'Login | Register'}
      </Link>
      <Link className={(this.props.currentActivePage === 'Dashboard')? "nav-item is-active" : "nav-item"} to="/dashboard">
       Dashboard
      </Link>
      <Link className={(this.props.currentActivePage === 'Account')? "nav-item is-active" : "nav-item"} to="/account">
       My Account
      </Link>
      <span className="nav-item">
       <a className="button is-dark" href="https://github.com/">
        <span className="icon">
         <i className="fa fa-github"></i>
        </span>
        <span>Github Repository</span>
       </a>
      </span>
     </div>
    </header>
   );
  }

  toggleMobileNav() {
   console.log('Got inside toggleMobileNav');
   this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    return {
     isMobile: !prevState.isMobile
    };
   });
  }
};
```

More information [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)